# Command for logging into an account using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, authentication, selenium-ide

I'm trying to test whether logging into an account is successful using Selenium IDE.

Is there a particular command that I can use in Selenium IDE to test whether I can successfully log into my account on facebook for instance? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single command to fill out an entire form. However, the `type` command can be used for each field:

[image]

Replace `username` with whatever the actual ID of each field is (which can be seen by right-clicking the page and viewing the page source). You can use many other HTML attributes in this manner, such as `name` and `class`; have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-by-identifier) for more examples.

Then, simply repeat this procedure for each field you wish to fill in. To actually log in, you'll need the `click` command targeting the Login button. This is used the same way as the `type` command above, but doesn't need anything in the Value field.

Once you're actually in, you can check if it was successful by using the `assertText` command, targeting something you know the value of (your profile name, for example). If Selenium-IDE can't find the element (or the name doesn't match), it'll let you know that the test has failed.